# How to access the next element below in HTML file using beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
<ns1:AffectedAreas>
      <ns1:Area>
        <ns1:AreaId>10YDK-1--------W</ns1:AreaId>
        <ns1:AreaName>DK1</ns1:AreaName>
      </ns1:Area>
</ns1:AffectedAreas>
```

I've been trying my best to access the `ns1:AreaId` which is `(10YDK-1--------W)` through `ns1:AffectedAreas` by using `B = soup.find('ns1:area')` and then `B.next_element` but all I get is an **empty string**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to iterate over the `soup.find('ns1:area')` childrens to find the `ns1:areaid` tag and then to get his text.

```
for i in soup.find('ns1:area').children:
    if i.name == "ns1:areaid":
        b = i.text
print(b)
```

And from `ns1:AffectedAreas` it will look like

```
for i in soup.find_all('ns1:AffectedAreas'.lower()):
    for child in i.children:
        if child.name == "ns1:area":
            for y in child.children:
                if y.name == "ns1:areaid":
                    print(y.text)
```

Or to search the tag `ns1:AreaId` in lower case and to get text of him. this way you can get all the text values from all `ns1:AreaId` tags.

```
soup.find_all("ns1:AreaId".lower())[0].text
```

Both cases will output

```
"10YDK-1--------W"
```

Comment: Is there any way to start the iteration on ns1:AffectedArea? That's where i really need to start.

Comment: Yes you can do soup.find('ns1:AffectedArea'.lower()).children

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'children' is the error i get

Comment: I've add to the answer the relevant code from `ns1:AffectedAreas`

Answer (score 0):

Try this method,

```
import bs4
import re

data = """
<ns1:AffectedAreas>
      <ns1:Area>
        <ns1:AreaId>10YDK-1--------W</ns1:AreaId>
        <ns1:AreaName>DK1</ns1:AreaName>
      </ns1:Area>
</ns1:AffectedAreas>
"""
def striphtml(data):
    p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
    return p.sub('', data)

bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
areaid = bs.find_all('ns1:areaid')
print((striphtml(str(areaid))))
```

Here, `striphtml` function will remove all the tags containing `<>`.So the output will be,

```
[10YDK-1--------W]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined namespaces in your HTML/XML document, you can use `xml` parser and CSS selectors.

For example:

```
txt = '''<root xmlns:ns1="some namespace">
    <ns1:AffectedAreas>
      <ns1:Area>
        <ns1:AreaId>10YDK-1--------W</ns1:AreaId>
        <ns1:AreaName>DK1</ns1:AreaName>
      </ns1:Area>
</ns1:AffectedAreas>
</root>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'xml')

area_id = soup.select_one('ns1|AffectedAreas ns1|AreaId').text
print(area_id)
```

Prints:

```
10YDK-1--------W
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, req, utils
html = '''
<ns1:AffectedAreas>
      <ns1:Area>
        <ns1:AreaId>10YDK-1--------W</ns1:AreaId>
        <ns1:AreaName>DK1</ns1:AreaName>
      </ns1:Area>
      <ns1:Area>
        <ns1:AreaId>10YDK-2--------W</ns1:AreaId>
        <ns1:AreaName>DK2</ns1:AreaName>
      </ns1:Area>
</ns1:AffectedAreas>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
AffectedArea = doc.select('ns1:AffectedAreas')
Areas =  AffectedArea.selects('ns1:Area')
AreaIds = Areas.select('ns1:AreaId').html
print (AreaIds)
# or
# print (doc.select('ns1:AffectedAreas').selects('ns1:Area').select('ns1:AreaId').html)
```

Result:

```
['10YDK-1--------W', '10YDK-2--------W']
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples